# Do BNO passport holders require a visa to transfer through Taiwan?

Tags: transit, hong-kong, taiwan

I'm wondering whether a British National Overseas passport holder requires a visa to transit through Taiwan. Basically, New York > Taiwan (4 hours) > Hong Kong.

Thanks!

Comment: Not true on a technical concern. My guess its officially they would class one being an overseas roc person using a british/prc document.
Since Taiwan does not admit prc, we use that entry permit form (when not transitting). And using the entry permit backing by the bno would make subsequent entries backed by prchksar passport undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only transiting, and staying airside, you don't need to apply for the Exit and Entry permit Taiwan requires from HK people of Chinese descent. Note that using a BNO or HK passport doesn't matter, as you will be in both cases treated as a HK PR of Chinese descent.